# Когда использовать классы с default областью видимости?

Tags: java, ооп, классы

Является ли использование классов без указания области видимости (default visibility) плохой практикой?

Если нет то приведите, пожалуйста, пример их использования.

```
public class X {
    // Какая-то логика...

}
class Y { // Класс без указания области видимости
    // Какая-то логика...
}
```

Comment: Что такое default класс? В первые слышу о таком

Comment: https://coderanch.com/t/390427/java/default-class-visibility

Comment: если доступ к классам не планируется вне пакета, то указывать им public нет никакой надобности

Answer (score 2):

*Пакетная видимость* может быть полезна, например, когда вы разрабатываете библиотеку: Пара тройка-классов библиотеки предназначены для непосредственного использования в коде других приложений - они объявляются публичными, а ещё десяток классов только для обеспечения внутренней логики библиотеки - они должны быть доступны только на уровне пакета.